# node entity not created in neo4j

Tags: spring, rest, neo4j, spring-data, resttemplate

I'm using rest template and I want to store the converted object (SignalDescription.class) in neo4j.

This is my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SignalTest {

    @Autowired
    private SignalRepository signalRepository;

    private SignalClient signalClient;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private String url;

    private SignalDescription signalDescription;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        url = "http://10.248.104.63:10001";

    }

    @Test
    public void testSignal() {

        signalClient = new SignalClient(restTemplate, url);
        signalDescription = signalClient.getSignalDescription("203");

        System.out.println(signalDescription.toString());

        //Save SignalDescription in database
        signalRepository.save(signalDescription);

    }
}
```

SignalRepository extends GraphRepository. SignalDescription is my node entity.

My SignalClient is:

```
@Service
public class SignalClient {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private String url;

    @Autowired
    public SignalClient(RestTemplate restTemplate, @Value("${metasql.url}") String url) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public SignalDescription getSignalDescription(String signalId) {

        return restTemplate.getForObject(url + "/v0/cache/signals/" + signalId, SignalDescription.class);
    }

}
```

After running the test, I got this result

```
Thread: 1, url: http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/10, request: {"statements":[{"statement":"UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n)=row.nodeId SET n:`SignalDescription` SET n += row.props RETURN row.nodeId as ref, ID(n) as id, row.type as type","parameters":{"rows":[{"type":"node","nodeId":203,"props":{"customerDesignation":"1.D30.03","name":"UNIT1.Ev_Grp30_E.Field_curcuit_breaker_open.Present","unitId":"0"}}]},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]}
```

But no CREATE statement is performed, as It occured with another example:

```
Thread: 1, url: http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/11, request: {"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH (n:`Product`) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r0]-() DELETE r0, n","parameters":{},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]}
2018-01-17 11:40:42.060  INFO 22039 --- [           main] o.n.o.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest   : Thread: 1, url: http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/12, request: {"statements":[{"statement":"UNWIND {rows} as row CREATE (n:`Product`) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as ref, ID(n) as id, row.type as type","parameters":{"rows":[{"nodeRef":-1,"type":"node","props":{"price":"100.0","imageUrl":"http://an-imageurl.com/image1.jpg","description":"ProductTest"}}]},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]}
```

Comment: the subject for thie post says not sotred in neo4j, in the description you say, it is stored but not displayed. clarify

Comment: you're right. Is stored but not displayed. I changed the topic name

Comment: if it is saved and not displayed. may be it has something to do with logging level.

Comment: how I can check it?

Comment: @pvpkiran I edited the post, the node is not created. But I tried with another node entity "Product" (but it doesn't come from restTemplate) and the CREATE statement is performed